# What are the .php~ files?

Tags: php

I am working on one [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) project, and I am having some files for that. Some of the files have anextension as

```
file_name.php~
```

What does it mean and how do those files get created?

Comment: Which editor are you using? ~ is a common postfix for auto-saved files.

Comment: Indeed, either an auto-save or a flag to show someone else has the file open (like MSOffice does).

Comment: @dutt: i am using notepad++. but with this how such files generates?

Comment: Notepad++ can also be configured to backup to a custom directory away from your current files. Or you can turn off the backup altogether.

Answer (score 11):

Those are backup files created by the text editor you are using (or one of the people working on the same project).

Comment: ... and they're very dangerous to have online because they may not be parsed by the PHP interpreter, revealing the source code including any passwords that may be contained therein.

Comment: And @Pekka is totally right!

Comment: Yes - although many default web server configurations include rules to forbid access to files beginning or ending in `~`, you must _not_ rely on that! Remove them from web-accessible locations immediately.

Comment: @X.L.Ant: how that back up generates? are there any steps to create it or automatically editor creates it. and specifically which editor. i am using notepad++

Comment: See praveen answer.

Comment: @user1794794: Do you work alone on your project ? If not, maybe it comes from another editor too.

Comment: The best answer is that you should *not* be editing your deployed files manually in the web server's directory.

Answer (score 5):

When you are working with files, editing them, the editor(almost all of them) creates a copy of it with names like you provided and does the editing on that file. Upon saving the file the changes are saved to the original files.

These files are generally **hidden** from the user. You are seeing it probably because the option to `show hidden files` is turned on.

When you quit from your text editor, that **temporary file** gets deleted.

Finally, You don't need to worry about the creation of those files :)

NOTE: JUST MAKE SURE YOU DON'T UPLOAD THEM TO THE SERVER WHICH CAN BE A SECURITY ISSUE AS DISCUSSED IN THE COMMENTS :)

Comment: Welcome :) And don't worry about those files :p

Comment: @praveen: You should worry about those files if you accidentally upload them to your live server (as Pekka points out on the other answer).

Comment: Yes! that is a point to worry! I just meant to tell him not to worry about why those files are created. :p